# configure can't find QT path

Tags: compiling, qt

trying to compile the 'quiteinsane' GIMP plugin, on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. When running configure, it complains that

"checking for Qt... configure: error: Qt (>= Qt 2.2.2) (headers and libraries) not found. Please check your installation!
"

qt is definitely installed, also the dev package libqt4-dev and libqt4-bin. Why can't it find it?

Tried specifying the path manually by `./configure --with-qt-libraries=/usr/include/qt4` but it's still failing. What am I missing, or how do I find and specify the correct path?

Searched the forums already, tried a few suggestions but nothing that resolved the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From where have you got `quiteinsane` source codes?

Comment: From the project's sourceforge page: https://sourceforge.net/projects/quiteinsane/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of v0.10 archive are dated 2004, it may not work at all.
And both GIMP with SANE APIs possibly changed.

So I would recommend to use GIMP from the repository with its actual plugins like `xsane` or `xscanimage`:

> [image: GIMP File menu]